# How to go get github.com/fxamacker/cbor/v2 with Go 1.10?

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, go-get

I tried running `go get -u github.com/fxamacker/cbor/v2`, but I get this error:

```
package github.com/fxamacker/cbor/v2: cannot find package "github.com/fxamacker/cbor/v2" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/fxamacker/cbor/v2 (from $GOROOT)
    /go/src/github.com/fxamacker/cbor/v2 (from $GOPATH)
```

I get the same error when I run without the `-u` flag.

I am using Go 1.10 because one of the requirements for my project is that it supports Windows Vista, and Go 1.10 is the latest version of Go that will build for Vista ([source](https://go.dev/doc/go1.10#ports)).

Here is a Dockerfile to reproduce this:

```
FROM golang:1.10.8-alpine@sha256:549535d72baf28b3d1470ef9fcc6d4e0cb52c7fc3012655a659b65eaf942ec63 as builder

RUN apk add --no-cache git

ENV GOOS=windows

ARG GOARCH

RUN go get -u github.com/fxamacker/cbor/v2
```

You can reproduce with the issue with the following command:

```
docker build -t test --build-arg GOARCH=386 .
```

This project is still available: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/fxamacker/cbor/v2

Why does my `go get` fail?

I looked at the [`go.mod`](https://github.com/fxamacker/cbor/blob/master/go.mod) for the package. It requires a minimum go of 1.12 on `master`. Could this be why the `go get` fails?

Comment: Yes, it is still available: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/fxamacker/cbor/v2. Please update to a supported version of Go.

Comment: I am using Go 1.10 because one of the requirements for my project is that it supports Windows Vista, and Go 1.10 is the latest version of Go that will build for Vista.

Comment: Most go packages only support modules, which were introduced in go1.11 many years ago. v2 of that package was released for go1.12 using modules in 2020.

Comment: I assume then that I could do something like `go get github.com/fxamacker/cbor@<some old version>` and that might work, assuming the version is one old enough to support Go 1.10?

Comment: Using `@` to specify the version in `go get` also doesn't work, presumably because Go 1.10 doesn't support that.

Comment: You can always manually clone a repo into GOPATH or `vendor/`, but seeing how that project didn't exist before modules, you may run into other problems with dependencies.

Comment: Did you try to build a program using a more recent version or go and try to run it on Vista? Or you MUST develop it on Vista?

Comment: Windows Vista End Of Life was over 5 years ago (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-vista ) these kinds of problems should be expected when running out dated operating systems.